# Ionic 3 HTTP GET – getting changes in the observable

Tags: ionic-framework, observable

I am creating a chat page in my ionic application and I would like to know when the get request changes.  I am also OK with doing this all off of an interval, but I can’t find a good example on how to do it.  I would prefer to not have to have the user refresh the page to see if a new chat message has appeared.  I am newer to observables and have not seen this done with the remote data source and the HTTP package. My data is already JSON so that's why it's not mentioned at all. Thanks!

Chat.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild ,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Events, Content } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ChatProvider } from "../../../../../providers/chat/chat";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";


export class ChatShowPage {
    public id:string;
    public items: Observable<ChatMessage[]> = [];

    constructor(navParams: NavParams, private chatService: ChatProvider, private events: Events,) {
        this.id = navParams.get('id_convo');
    }
    getMsg() {
        return this.chatService.getMsgList(this.id).subscribe(res => {
                this.items=res;
                console.log(this.items);
            });
    }
}
```

Provider.ts

```
getMsgList(id): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    const msgListUrl = this.base_url + 'user/account/chat/show/' + id;
    console.log('getMsgList - ' + msgListUrl);

    return this.http.get<any>(msgListUrl,
            {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('tk') })});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) to update your component

In this particular example, you could use:

```
 ionViewWillLeave() {
 // unsubscribe
  this.events.unsubscribe('chat:received');
 }

ionViewDidEnter() {
 //get message list
 this.getMsg();

 // Subscribe to received  new message events
 this.events.subscribe('chat:received', msg => {
   this.pushNewMsg(msg);
 })
}
```

In your `provider.ts` your `getMsgList` function should emit the `chat:received` event  as such:

```
      this.events.publish('chat:received')
```

Then in your `pushNewMsg` function, you would do some safety checks and then push the new message into the array which you can display with an *ngFor directive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two famous ways to make chat module via web(including ionic).

1. [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science))
2. [WebSocket (Event-driven)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

**Polling**
: If you make simple or personal chat application and want to keep current code structure, then you'd better use polling pattern which merely repeat request with some interval. In addition, for better polling, please consider [HTTP Long Polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/)

`setTimeout()` with recursion or `setInterval()` can be options.

**WebSocket (Event-driven)**
: If you make commercial application or application with lots of users, then you have to use Event-driven pattern. For using this pattern, both of server-side work and client-side work are needed. If you use **node.js** as server-side framework, then I recommend to use [Socket.IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO).

Comment: Thank you but that's not the question that I asked